# clicked on radio button one time but input box is generating more than 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am generating a dynamic Input box with radio button selection.
I am doing but problem is there.

Using a Select box i am generating a Radio button html and then from radio button,
I am trying to generate only one input box on selection of every last radio button.

**Problem**: when i have clicked on radio button one time then Why input box is generating more than 1.

**jsfiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/4A4FY/

[image].

**Jquery**

```
  $("input[data-target='generateInput']").on('click', function (e) {
        var targetId = $(this).parent("div").attr("id");
        var t = $("div#input_" + targetId).append("<input type='text' name='aa' />");
    });
```

**HTML**

```
    <select id="e1" name='selectTag' multiple>
     <option value="ABC" data-id='1' id='1'>ABC</option>
     <option value="DEF" data-id='2' id='2'>DEF</option>
     <option value="GHI" data-id='3' id='3'>GHI</option>
     <option value="JKL" data-id='4' id='4'>JKL</option>
     <option value="MNO" data-id='5' id='5'>MNO</option>
   </select>
   <div id='generate' style='margin:10px;'></div>
```

Comment: The html seems irrelevant to the question..

Comment: please check in jsfiddle link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an expected behavior, Because you are appending the elements into the target element,

Try to use `.html()` at this context to accomplish your task..

```
$("input[data-target='generateInput']").on('click', function (e) {
    var targetId = $(this).parent("div").attr("id");
    var t = $("div#input_" + targetId).html("<input type='text' name='aa' />");
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4A4FY/1/)

Or write a condition to block the code flow if input has been appended already,

```
$("input[data-target='generateInput']").on('click', function (e) {
    var targetId = $(this).parent("div").attr("id");
    var elem = $("div#input_" + targetId);
    if(elem.find('input[name=aa]').length) { return; }
    var t = elem.append("<input type='text' name='aa' />");
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4A4FY/3/)

Answer (score 1):

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4A4FY/2/)

Use `.one('click..')` - (**[reference](http://api.jquery.com/one/)**) to add it only once.

```
$("input[data-target='generateInput']").one('click', function(e) {
    var targetId= $(this).parent("div").attr("id");
    console.log("#input_"+targetId);
    var t = $("div#input_"+targetId).append("<input type='text' name='aa' />"); 
});
```

*Side Note*: If you click twice on an `<option>` it is generating duplicate IDs

Comment: thnx for your effort. but solved with @Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy ans.. :)